# Should I use () or {} when forwarding arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

I have the following class:

```
struct foo
{
    std::size_t _size;
    int* data;
public:
    explicit foo(std::size_t s) : _size(s) { }
    foo(std::size_t s, int v)
        : _size(s)
    {
        data = new int[_size];
        std::fill(&data[0], &data[0] + _size, v);
    }

    foo(std::initializer_list<int> d)
        : _size(d.size())
    {
        data = new int[_size];
        std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), &data[0]);
    }

    ~foo() { delete[] data; }

    std::size_t size() const { return _size; }
};
```

And I want to forward arguments to it like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto forward_args(Args&&... args)
{
    return foo{std::forward<Args>(args)...}.size();
    //--------^---------------------------^
}

std::cout << forward_args(1, 2) << " " << forward_args(1) << " " 
          << forward_args(2) << "\n";
```

If I replace `{}` with `()` the output is `1 1 2` instead of `2 1 1`.

Which would make the most sense for my class?

Comment: "Which would make the most sense for my class?" This depends on what you want your class to do. `{}` prefers `std::initializer_list`, `()` does not. That's where the difference comes from. Only *you* know how you want the class to behave, and therefore what it should do.

Comment: You should avoid to have these concurrent constructors, you may add some tag to be explicit: `foo(size_with_value_tag, std::size_t s, int v)`.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `{}` vs. `()` determines which constructor is called.

- The `{}` will call the form `foo(std::initializer_list<int> d)` and you get the results you seem to expect.
- The `()` will call the `explicit foo(std::size_t s)` and `foo(std::size_t s, int v)`, and in all cases, the first element is the size, so given the arguments, you get the results you see.

Which form to favour depends on what semantics you want the `forward_args` method to support. If you want the parameters to be passed "as is", then the `()` should be used (in this case the user will need to provide an `initialiser_list` as an argument to begin with).

Possibly (probably) the **form you wish to favour is `()` and used as follows**;

```
template <typename... Args>
auto forward_args(Args&&... args)
{
    return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...).size();
    //--------^---------------------------^
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << forward_args(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2}) << " "
              << forward_args(std::initializer_list<int>{3}) << " " 
              << forward_args(std::initializer_list<int>{4}) << "\n";
}
```

*Side note*; the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) on the `initializer_list` has a good example of this behaviour.

If desired (i.e. to support `forward_args({1,2})`), **you can provide an overload for `initializer_list`**;

```
template <class Arg>
auto forward_args(std::initializer_list<Arg> arg)
{
    return foo(std::move(arg)).size();
}
```

---

As noted: given the `initializer_list`, the class constructors are ultimately the source of the confusion, and this presents itself during the object construction. There is a difference between `foo(1,2)` and `foo{1,2}`; the latter calls the `initializer_list` form of the constructor. One technique to resolve this is to use a "tag" to differentiate the "normal" constructor forms from the `initializer_list` form.

Comment: The case of a class with no ctors at all is supported by `{}`.

Comment: @Yakk, true. `std::make_unique` suffers with this as well; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a95e11d3238ea9c

Answer (score 2):

In this case, because the class has a constructor which take an `std::initializer_list`, using `{}` in the factory function will often change the semantic meaning of any argument list you pass in - by turning any pack of arguments longer than 2 into an initializer_list.

This will be surprising to users of the function.

Therefore, use the `()` form. Users who want to pass an initializer_list may to so explicitly by calling

```
forward_args({ ... });
```

NB for the above syntax to work you'll need to provide another overload:

```
template <class T>
auto forward_args(std::initializer_list<T> li)
{
    return foo(li).size();
}
```

Comment: *"may to so explicitly by calling"*, you probably mean `forward_args(std::initializer_list<type>{ ... });`, otherwise it won't be deduced

Comment: Makes sense. All standard libraries I've tried use `()` to forward inside `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you shouldn't be defining your class `foo` like this (provided it is within your control). The two constructors have an overlap and result in a bad situation where the two initializations:

```
foo f1(3);
foo f2{3};
```

Mean two different things; and people who need to write forwarding functions face unsolvable problems. This is covered in detail in [this blog post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/intuitive-interface-part-i/). Also `std::vector` suffers from the same problem.

Instead, I propose you use a 'tagged' constructor:

```
struct with_size {}; // just a tag

struct foo
{
    explicit foo(with_size, std::size_t s);

    explicit foo(with_size, std::size_t s, int v);

    foo(std::initializer_list<int> d);

    // ...
}
```

Now you have no overlap, and you can safely use the {} variant.

Comment: You can also use `struct foo_size{ std::size_t size; }` then `foo( foo_size )` non-explicitly.  Admittedly `foo({1})` is still confusing.  :)