# Why don't std::initializer_list overloads exist for std::make_unique et al?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, uniform-initialization

See [Should I use () or {} when forwarding arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158899/should-i-use-or-when-forwarding-arguments). `foo` is a `std::vector` clone.

In N4140, [unique.ptr.create](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.create) `std::make_unique` is specified as so:

> `template <class T, class... Args> unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args);`
>
> - *Remarks*: This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless `T` is not an array.
> - *Returns*: `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.

That means implementations are required to use `()` rather than `{}` to initialize objects. As an example, the following

```
auto s1 = std::make_unique<foo>(3, 1).get()->size();
auto s2 = std::make_unique<foo>(1).get()->size();
auto s3 = std::make_unique<foo>(2).get()->size();
std::cout << s1 << s2 << s3;
```

outputs `312` whereas if `{}` (inside `std::make_unique`) was used `211` would be output. Because initializer lists cannot be deduced, `std::initializer_list` must be explicitly passed in order to get the latter result. The question is, why isn't an overload like this provided?

```
namespace test
{

template <class T, class Deduce>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(std::initializer_list<Deduce> li)
{
    return ::std::make_unique<T>(li);
}

};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = test::make_unique<foo>({3, 1}).get()->size();
    auto p2 = test::make_unique<foo>({1}).get()->size();
    auto p3 = test::make_unique<foo>({2}).get()->size();
    std::cout << p1 << p2 << p3;
}
```

Outputs `211`.

I don't consider the reasons "you can write it yourself" or "to avoid bloating the standard" to be very good reasons. Is there any disadvantages to providing this overload?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the complete history, but the most likely answer is "nobody proposed it".

Evidence for this is supported by the fact that `std::make_unique` was only added in C++14, yet `std::unique_ptr` existed in C++11.

The code and proposals for `std::make_shared` (which was eventually mirrored in `make_unique`) existed (in boost) prior to the `initializer_list` and the initialisation syntax supporting it.

One thing you could do now, is to propose it (and work out the corner cases if there are any, e.g. use SFINAE to remove the overload if the target type doesn't support the `initializer_list`).

Comment: I don't think SFINAE is necessary. `make_unique<std::pair<int, int>>(1, 73);` works perfectly fine if I take it out of the namespace and do `using namespace std;` (to make sure both overloads are visible). If somebody does `make_unique<std::pair<int, int>>({1, 73});` that's their fault.

Comment: @user6319825. Yes, the SFINAE is not essential, the compile fails either way, just in my experience the error messages in a SFINAE environment are "easier" to diagnose.

Comment: Still. They deliberate said `new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` rather than leave it up to the implementation like for [optional](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.object.ctor#23): "Initializes the contained value as if direct-non-list-initializing an object of type `T` with the arguments `std::forward<Args>(args)`...." That makes me think there's some discussion *somewhere* at least for `make_unique` specifically.

Comment: Interesting to note; [`optional` caters for the `initializer_list`](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.object.ctor#31)

Comment: @user6319825. The wording is different, probably had different authors for each section. I like the idea of the overload, it would be handy. Probably worth proposing somehow.

Comment: @Niall I find that overload is awesome to make perfect forwarding more perfect.  I wonder if I learned it from an early optional proposal?

Comment: @Yakk. Possibly. I like some of the tag techniques used in the code that came through around about that time as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a template deduction issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431810/1887915).

You could try these:

```
int main()
{
    auto p1 = std::make_unique<foo>(std::initializer_list<int>{3, 1}).get()->size();
    auto p2 = std::make_unique<foo>(foo{1}).get()->size();
    auto l3 = {2};
    auto p3 = std::make_unique<foo>(l3).get()->size();
    std::cout << p1 << p2 << p3;
}
```